# Replaces text.number to number

Tags: excel

I have a excel cells with username.id.I want to delete usernames and I just want ID's to be displayed in cells.

EG: sunny.123 should be transformed to 123

Comment: same question as @pnuts. also numbers appear only 1 time in the string like your example and does it always come after `.` (dot)? please clarify what you need so we can better help you.

Comment: What is so unclear about this question to get it closed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1))*1
```

This assumes that your IDs are always using the schema `String.Number`

If this is not always the case, this formula handles a few more situation:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(".",A1)),IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,"Pattern does not match User.Id!"),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1))*1)
```